# kext file fails to load after updating to Mac OS X 10.11.2

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, codesign, kernel-extension, driver-signing

I have a kext file that was able to load on Mac OS X 10.11.1 but after updating to Mac OS X 10.11.2 it fails to load.

**Mac OS X 10.11.1**
When executing `sudo kextload abc.kext` command is successful and when executing `sudo kextutil -tn abc.kext` the output is `/System/Library/Extensions/ch34xsigned.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).`

**Mac OS X 10.11.2**
When executing `sudo kextload abc.kext` output is `/System/Library/Extensions/abc.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).` and when executing `sudo kextutil -tn abc.kext` the output is `Code Signing Failure: not code signed
/System/Library/Extensions/ch34xsigned.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).`

As far as I understand there was nothing related to drivers signing on this release. 
The list of changes in this update include:

- Improved Wi-Fi reliability
- Improved the reliability of Handoff and AirDrop
- Fixed an issue that may cause Bluetooth devices to disconnect
- Fixed an issue that prevented Mail from deleting messages in an
  offline Exchange account
- Fixed an issue that prevented importing
  photos from an iPhone to a Mac using a USB cable
- Improved iCloud Photo Sharing for Live Photos

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to CVE-2015-7052; unfortunately the details aren't public, and source is not yet available. You're probably better off asking on Apple's forums, or DTS.

However, I notice you're using /System/Library/Extensions/ - as this directory has not been intended for third party kexts since 10.19/10.10, and indeed is usually unavailable due to SIP on 10.11 (you evidently have SIP turned off) try /Library/Extensions instead.

Comment: I will try Apple's forum. I am aware that since Mac OS X 10.9 third party kexts should be installed in /Library/Extensions however, the kext was successfully loaded on Mac OS X 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11.1 even if it was installed in /System/Library/Extensions. I have checked and SIP is turned on on both Mac OS X 10.11.1 and Mac OS X 10.11.2. If I turn off SIP on Mac OS X 10.11.2, kext loads successfully as well.

Comment: I realise it used to work in /SLE on 10.9 and 10.10, and indeed there were certain kext cache bugs that required using /SLE in some cases. However, due to SIP, /SLE is no longer writable on 10.11, and the kext cache bugs for /LE are fixed, so I would not be surprised if Apple checked that the kext's signature is Apple's own for /SLE. I'd give /LE a try, it may just fix your problem.

Comment: I will try to change the installation directory to /Library/Extensions and let you know if it works. Thanks!